# PHP can't write to a directory

Tags: php, permissions, iis-7.5, file-permissions

I am trying to configure our server for a client's website that we host. Their site is PHP, which I'm not terribly familiar with, so I don't know if it works in some weird way. (All our sites are in ASP.)

They manage their own site generally, via FTP. They are trying to add **`sphiderplus`** to the site, which is where these issues started.

After logging in to sphiderplus, you receive numerous copies of this error (for a number of files and folders under the sphiderplus root):

```
Attention: Sphider-plus is unable to set full write permission 
to the <filename> file in <foldername> folder.
 Might cause problems for command line operation.
 Modify the according server settings for PHP scripts.
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to give PHP the proper permissions for sphiderplus to run properly. Here are the steps I've taken so far after googling around, which did not work...

- created a separate application pool for the PHP site
- created a separate local user for the above app pool
- gave that local user `Full Control` rights on the sphiderplus root directory (with propagation)
- gave **`IUSR`** `Full Control` rights on the sphiderplus root directory (with propagation)
- gave **`IIS_IUSRS`** `Full Control` rights on the sphiderplus root directory (with propagation)
- gave **`NETWORK SERVICE`** `Full Control` rights on the sphiderplus root directory (with propagation)

... and then just for fun, when it still wouldn't work, to test,

- gave **`Everyone`** `Full Control` rights on the sphiderplus root directory (with propagation)

I don't know what else to try. Is there maybe some sort of `ini` or `config` file that I need to change some lines in or something? I really would've thought, if nothing else, then giving **`Everyone`** full control on the whole sphiderplus directory would've worked. I'm not really sure what else to do.

We are running

- PHP 7.0.5 installed from Microsoft's Web Platform Installer
- FastCGI installed from Micosoft's Web Platform Installer
- IIS 7.5.7600.16385
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (v 6.1 b 7601).

Comment: Nobody? Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I got around this by changing how it was checking the writability of the files/folders.

The sphiderplus code was checking like this...

```
$perms = substr(decoct(fileperms("$tmp_dir/thread_ids.txt")), 2);
if ($perms != '0777') { /* output message */ }
```

I changed that code to this...

```
if(!is_writable("$tmp_dir/thread_ids.txt")) { /* ouput message */ }
```

Seems to work fine.